# .Net Native Internal Compiler Error NUTC3028 when overriding mixed generic methods

Tags: c#, uwp, mathnet-numerics, coreclr, .net-native

I'm running into an internal compiler error NUTC3028 when trying to compile a trivial UWP app in release mode with a dependency on the [MathNet.Numerics](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MathNet.Numerics/) NuGet package (PCL Profile7). 
[Related Github Issue](https://github.com/mathnet/mathnet-numerics/issues/361).

```
NUTC3028:Internal Compiler Error: Method

  'instance Tuple<int, int, T, TOther>
   DenseColumnMajorMatrixStorage<T>.Find2Unchecked<TOther>(MatrixStorage<TOther>,
   Func<T,TOther,bool>, Zeros)'

on type

  'DenseColumnMajorMatrixStorage<T>'

from assembly

  'MathNet.Numerics'

tried to implicitly override a method with weaker type parameter
constraints while loading type

  'DenseColumnMajorMatrixStorage<T>'.

while computing compilation roots.
```

`DenseColumnMajorMatrixStorage<T>` inherits from `MatrixStorage<T>`, both of them with the same constraint `where T : struct, IEquatable<T>, IFormattable`.

`override DenseColumnMajorMatrixStorage<T>.Find2Unchecked<TOther>(..)` overrides `virtual MatrixStorage<T>.Find2Unchecked<TOther>(..)`, the latter with again the same constaint for the generic method type parameter: `where TOther : struct, IEquatable<TOther>, IFormattable`. In C# it is not possible to change or even declare constraints when overriding, so there is no additional constraints in the overriding method.

- [Sources of DenseColumnMajorMatrixStorage.Find2Unchecked](https://github.com/mathnet/mathnet-numerics/blob/1d01002cdbdf28c0ad4fb438332782881f568fec/src/Numerics/LinearAlgebra/Storage/DenseColumnMajorMatrixStorage.cs#L702)
- [Sources of MatrixStorage.Find2Unchecked](https://github.com/mathnet/mathnet-numerics/blob/1d01002cdbdf28c0ad4fb438332782881f568fec/src/Numerics/LinearAlgebra/Storage/MatrixStorage.cs#L658)

I'm not quite following what type parameter constraints are supposed to be weaker; they look exactly the same to me. What am I missing?

*Warning: reproducing this may take a while; on my machine ilc runs for roughly two hours (sic!) before failing with the error*

Comment: If you haven't done so already, try building the app with the latest [Visual Studio Tools for Universal Windows Apps](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/vs2015-update1-vs.aspx#uniwinapps). If you can still reproduce the issue, I would suggest to report it to dotnetnative@microsoft.com.

Comment: Yikes! I work on the .NET Native team and would like to take a look at this. Can you follow the instructions here? : https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/Documentation/ilcRepro.md

Answer (score 2):

I think this is corrected if you move to Windows Tools 1.3.1 (aka VS 2015 Update 2). You can see more discussion about it here: https://github.com/mathnet/mathnet-numerics/issues/361

Do let me know if you find that to not be the case.